# How to port code using sys/ioctl.h to MinGW gcc?

Tags: windows, matlab, gcc, mingw-w64, msys2

My codes (https://github.com/fangq/mmc, https://github.com/fangq/mcxcl) have been compiled out-of-box using gcc on Linux & Mac, cygwin-gcc or msys2-gcc on Windows, but not with MinGW compilers (`x86-64-mingw64-*` compilers for cygwin64, msys2, mingw64 or TDM-GCC, or [matlab mingw64 support (mingw64 gcc 4.9.6)](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/52848-matlab-support-for-mingw-w64-c-c-compiler)) because it complains that it misses a set of header files (`sys/ioctl.h`, `ieee754.h` etc), so I included a copy of these header files in my source code, and added `-I./mingw64/include` to make most of them compile

https://github.com/fangq/mmc/tree/master/src/mingw64/include

however, when compiling the matlab mex file using [this script](https://github.com/fangq/mmc/blob/master/src/buildmmc.m) on MATLAB R2016/2018, I received the below error

```
Error using mex
mcx_utils.o: In function `mcx_progressbar':
D:/Users/fangq/Gitroot/Project/mmc/src/mcx_utils.c:1054: undefined reference to `ioctl'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am wondering why compiling inside matlab and outside matlab are different. Is there a library that I can link to fix the `undefined reference to "ioctl"` error?

Here is the log when compiling using gcc on msys2:

```
fangq@zen:~/space/git/Project/mmc/src$ make mex
Building built/xorshift128p_rand.o
cc -c -Wall -g -DMCX_EMBED_CL -fno-strict-aliasing -m64 -DMMC_USE_SSE -DHAVE_SSE2 -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4.1 -O3 -fopenmp   -DMCX_CONTAINER -DUSE_OS_TIMER -DUSE_OPENCL -DMMC_XORSHIFT -I../src -I"./mingw64/include" -o built/xorshift128p_rand.o  xorshift128p_rand.c
Building built/simpmesh.o
cc -c -Wall -g -DMCX_EMBED_CL -fno-strict-aliasing -m64 -DMMC_USE_SSE -DHAVE_SSE2 -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4.1 -O3 -fopenmp   -DMCX_CONTAINER -DUSE_OS_TIMER -DUSE_OPENCL -DMMC_XORSHIFT -I../src -I"./mingw64/include" -o built/simpmesh.o  simpmesh.c
Building built/tettracing.o
cc -c -Wall -g -DMCX_EMBED_CL -fno-strict-aliasing -m64 -DMMC_USE_SSE -DHAVE_SSE2 -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4.1 -O3 -fopenmp   -DMCX_CONTAINER -DUSE_OS_TIMER -DUSE_OPENCL -DMMC_XORSHIFT -I../src -I"./mingw64/include" -o built/tettracing.o  tettracing.c
Building built/mcx_utils.o
cc -c -Wall -g -DMCX_EMBED_CL -fno-strict-aliasing -m64 -DMMC_USE_SSE -DHAVE_SSE2 -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4.1 -O3 -fopenmp   -DMCX_CONTAINER -DUSE_OS_TIMER -DUSE_OPENCL -DMMC_XORSHIFT -I../src -I"./mingw64/include" -o built/mcx_utils.o  mcx_utils.c
Building built/tictoc.o
cc -c -Wall -g -DMCX_EMBED_CL -fno-strict-aliasing -m64 -DMMC_USE_SSE -DHAVE_SSE2 -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4.1 -O3 -fopenmp   -DMCX_CONTAINER -DUSE_OS_TIMER -DUSE_OPENCL -DMMC_XORSHIFT -I../src -I"./mingw64/include" -o built/tictoc.o  tictoc.c
Building built/mmc.o
cc -c -Wall -g -DMCX_EMBED_CL -fno-strict-aliasing -m64 -DMMC_USE_SSE -DHAVE_SSE2 -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4.1 -O3 -fopenmp   -DMCX_CONTAINER -DUSE_OS_TIMER -DUSE_OPENCL -DMMC_XORSHIFT -I../src -I"./mingw64/include" -o built/mmc.o  mmc.c
Building built/cjson/cJSON.o
cc -c -Wall -g -DMCX_EMBED_CL -fno-strict-aliasing -m64 -DMMC_USE_SSE -DHAVE_SSE2 -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4.1 -O3 -fopenmp   -DMCX_CONTAINER -DUSE_OS_TIMER -DUSE_OPENCL -DMMC_XORSHIFT -I../src -I"./mingw64/include" -o built/cjson/cJSON.o  cjson/cJSON.c
Building built/mmc_host.o
cc -c -Wall -g -DMCX_EMBED_CL -fno-strict-aliasing -m64 -DMMC_USE_SSE -DHAVE_SSE2 -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4.1 -O3 -fopenmp   -DMCX_CONTAINER -DUSE_OS_TIMER -DUSE_OPENCL -DMMC_XORSHIFT -I../src -I"./mingw64/include" -o built/mmc_host.o  mmc_host.c
Building built/highordermesh.o
g++ -c -Wall -g -DMCX_EMBED_CL -fno-strict-aliasing -m64 -DMMC_USE_SSE -DHAVE_SSE2 -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4.1 -O3 -fopenmp   -DMCX_CONTAINER -DUSE_OS_TIMER -DUSE_OPENCL -DMMC_XORSHIFT -I../src -I"./mingw64/include" -o built/highordermesh.o  highordermesh.cpp
Building built/mmc_cl_utils.o
cc -c -Wall -g -DMCX_EMBED_CL -fno-strict-aliasing -m64 -DMMC_USE_SSE -DHAVE_SSE2 -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4.1 -O3 -fopenmp   -DMCX_CONTAINER -DUSE_OS_TIMER -DUSE_OPENCL -DMMC_XORSHIFT -I../src -I"./mingw64/include" -o built/mmc_cl_utils.o  mmc_cl_utils.c
Building built/mmc_cl_host.o
cc -c -Wall -g -DMCX_EMBED_CL -fno-strict-aliasing -m64 -DMMC_USE_SSE -DHAVE_SSE2 -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4.1 -O3 -fopenmp   -DMCX_CONTAINER -DUSE_OS_TIMER -DUSE_OPENCL -DMMC_XORSHIFT -I../src -I"./mingw64/include" -o built/mmc_cl_host.o  mmc_cl_host.c
Building bin/mmc
cmd //c mex.bat   -v -f mexopts_msys2_gcc.xml COMPFLAGS='$COMPFLAGS -c -Wall -g -DMCX_EMBED_CL -fno-strict-aliasing -m64 -DMMC_USE_SSE -DHAVE_SSE2 -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4.1 -O3 -fopenmp   -DMCX_CONTAINER -DUSE_OS_TIMER -DUSE_OPENCL -DMMC_XORSHIFT' LDFLAGS='$LDFLAGS -static -fopenmp "c:\Windows\System32\OpenCL.dll" -fopenmp'  -outdir ../mmclab mmclab.cpp -I../src -I"./mingw64/include" -output bin/mmc built/xorshift128p_rand.o built/simpmesh.o built/tettracing.o built/mcx_utils.o built/tictoc.o built/mmc.o built/cjson/cJSON.o built/mmc_host.o built/highordermesh.o built/mmc_cl_utils.o built/mmc_cl_host.o
Verbose mode is on.
... Looking for compiler 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)' ...
... Looking for environment variable 'MW_MINGW64_LOC' ...Yes ('C:/msys64/usr/').
... Looking for file 'C:\msys64\usr\bin\g++.exe' ...Yes.
... Looking for folder 'C:\msys64\usr' ...Yes.
... Looking for environment variable 'MW_MINGW64_LOC' ...Yes ('C:/msys64/usr/').
... Executing command 'C:\msys64\usr\bin\g++ -dumpmachine' ...Yes ('x86_64-pc-msys').
Found installed compiler 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)'.
Set PATH = C:\msys64\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\extern\include\win64;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\extern\include;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\simulink\include;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\lib\win64;.;C:\msys64\opt\local\bin;C:\msys64\usr\local\cuda\bin\;.;C:\msys64\pub\bin;C:\msys64\pub\pgi\linux86-64\18.4\bin;C:\msys64\mingw64\bin;C:\msys64\usr\local\bin;C:\msys64\usr\bin;C:\msys64\usr\bin;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\msys64\usr\bin\site_perl;C:\msys64\usr\bin\vendor_perl;C:\msys64\usr\bin\core_perl;C:\msys64\usr\local\bin;C:\msys64\home\users\fangq\space\Download\MCXStudio;C;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\bin;C:\msys64\usr\lib\gcc\x86_64-pc-msys\9.3.0\
Set INCLUDE = C:\msys64\usr\include;C:\msys64\usr\x86_64-pc-msys\include\c++;C:\msys64\usr\x86_64-pc-msys\include;C:\msys64\usr\x86_64-pc-msys\include\c++\x86_64-pc-msys;C:\msys64\usr\x86_64-pc-msys\include\c++\backward;
Set LIB = C:\msys64\usr\lib;;
Set MW_TARGET_ARCH = win64;
Set LIBPATH = C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\extern\lib\win64;
Options file details
-------------------------------------------------------------------
        Compiler location: C:\msys64\usr
        Options file: C:\msys64\home\fangq\space\git\Project\mmc\src\mexopts_msys2_gcc.xml
        CMDLINE2 : C:\msys64\usr\bin\g++ -m64 -Wl,--no-undefined -static -fopenmp "c:\Windows\System32\OpenCL.dll" -fopenmp -shared -static -s -Wl,"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/exportsmexfileversion.def" C:\msys64\tmp\mex_1481040925092289_7396\mmclab.obj C:\msys64\tmp\mex_1481040925092289_7396\cpp_mexapi_version.obj "built/xorshift128p_rand.o" "built/simpmesh.o" "built/tettracing.o" "built/mcx_utils.o" "built/tictoc.o" "built/mmc.o" "built/cjson/cJSON.o" "built/mmc_host.o" "built/highordermesh.o" "built/mmc_cl_utils.o" "built/mmc_cl_host.o"  -L"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\extern\lib\win64\mingw64" -llibmx -llibmex -llibmat -o C:\msys64\home\fangq\space\git\Project\mmc\mmclab\mmc.mexw64
        CXX : C:\msys64\usr\bin\g++
        COMPILER : C:\msys64\usr\bin\g++
        DEFINES : -DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE
        MATLABMEX : -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE
        CFLAGS :  -c -Wall -g -DMCX_EMBED_CL -fno-strict-aliasing -m64 -DMMC_USE_SSE -DHAVE_SSE2 -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4.1 -O3 -fopenmp   -DMCX_CONTAINER -DUSE_OS_TIMER -DUSE_OPENCL -DMMC_XORSHIFT -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer
        CXXFLAGS :  -c -Wall -g -DMCX_EMBED_CL -fno-strict-aliasing -m64 -DMMC_USE_SSE -DHAVE_SSE2 -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4.1 -O3 -fopenmp   -DMCX_CONTAINER -DUSE_OS_TIMER -DUSE_OPENCL -DMMC_XORSHIFT -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer
        INCLUDE : -I"..\src" -I".\mingw64\include"  -I"C:\msys64\usr\usr\include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a/extern/include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a/simulink/include"
        CXXOPTIMFLAGS : -O -DNDEBUG
        CXXDEBUGFLAGS : -g
        LDXX : C:\msys64\usr\bin\g++
        LINKER : C:\msys64\usr\bin\g++
        LDFLAGS : -m64 -Wl,--no-undefined -static -fopenmp "c:\Windows\System32\OpenCL.dll" -fopenmp
        LDTYPE : -shared -static
        LINKEXPORT : -Wl,"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/mexFunction.def"
        LINKEXPORTVER : -Wl,"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/exportsmexfileversion.def"
        LIBLOC : C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\extern\lib\win64\mingw64
        LINKLIBS : -L"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\extern\lib\win64\mingw64" -llibmx -llibmex -llibmat
        LDOPTIMFLAGS : -s
        LDDEBUGFLAGS : -g
        OBJEXT : .obj
        LDEXT : .mexw64
        SETENV : set COMPILER=C:\msys64\usr\bin\gcc
                set CXXCOMPILER=C:\msys64\usr\bin\g++
                set COMPFLAGS=-c  -c -Wall -g -DMCX_EMBED_CL -fno-strict-aliasing -m64 -DMMC_USE_SSE -DHAVE_SSE2 -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4.1 -O3 -fopenmp   -DMCX_CONTAINER -DUSE_OS_TIMER -DUSE_OPENCL -DMMC_XORSHIFT -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE
                set CXXCOMPFLAGS=-c  -c -Wall -g -DMCX_EMBED_CL -fno-strict-aliasing -m64 -DMMC_USE_SSE -DHAVE_SSE2 -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4.1 -O3 -fopenmp   -DMCX_CONTAINER -DUSE_OS_TIMER -DUSE_OPENCL -DMMC_XORSHIFT -DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE
                set OPTIMFLAGS=-O -DNDEBUG
                set DEBUGFLAGS=-g
                set LINKER=C:\msys64\usr\bin\gcc
                set CXXLINKER=C:\msys64\usr\bin\g++
                set LINKFLAGS=-m64 -Wl,--no-undefined -static -fopenmp "c:\Windows\System32\OpenCL.dll" -fopenmp -shared -static -L"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\extern\lib\win64\mingw64" -llibmx -llibmex -llibmat -Wl,"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/mexFunction.def"
                set LINKDEBUGFLAGS=-g
                set NAME_OUTPUT= -o "%OUTDIR%%MEX_NAME%%MEX_EXT%"
        MINGWROOT : C:\msys64\usr
        MINGWTARGET : x86_64-pc-msys
        MATLABROOT : C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a
        ARCH : win64
        SRC : "C:\msys64\home\fangq\space\git\Project\mmc\src\mmclab.cpp";"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\extern\version\cpp_mexapi_version.cpp"
        OBJ : C:\msys64\tmp\mex_1481040925092289_7396\mmclab.obj;C:\msys64\tmp\mex_1481040925092289_7396\cpp_mexapi_version.obj
        OBJS : C:\msys64\tmp\mex_1481040925092289_7396\mmclab.obj C:\msys64\tmp\mex_1481040925092289_7396\cpp_mexapi_version.obj "built/xorshift128p_rand.o" "built/simpmesh.o" "built/tettracing.o" "built/mcx_utils.o" "built/tictoc.o" "built/mmc.o" "built/cjson/cJSON.o" "built/mmc_host.o" "built/highordermesh.o" "built/mmc_cl_utils.o" "built/mmc_cl_host.o"
        SRCROOT : C:\msys64\home\fangq\space\git\Project\mmc\src\mmclab
        DEF : C:\msys64\tmp\mex_1481040925092289_7396\mmc.def
        EXP : "C:\msys64\home\fangq\space\git\Project\mmc\mmclab\mmc.exp"
        LIB : "C:\msys64\home\fangq\space\git\Project\mmc\mmclab\mmc.lib"
        EXE : C:\msys64\home\fangq\space\git\Project\mmc\mmclab\mmc.mexw64
        ILK : "C:\msys64\home\fangq\space\git\Project\mmc\mmclab\mmc.ilk"
        MANIFEST : "C:\msys64\home\fangq\space\git\Project\mmc\mmclab\mmc.mexw64.manifest"
        TEMPNAME : C:\msys64\home\fangq\space\git\Project\mmc\mmclab\mmc
        EXEDIR : C:\msys64\home\fangq\space\git\Project\mmc\mmclab\
        EXENAME : mmc
        COMPFLAGS :  -c -Wall -g -DMCX_EMBED_CL -fno-strict-aliasing -m64 -DMMC_USE_SSE -DHAVE_SSE2 -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4.1 -O3 -fopenmp   -DMCX_CONTAINER -DUSE_OS_TIMER -DUSE_OPENCL -DMMC_XORSHIFT
        OPTIM : -O -DNDEBUG
        LINKOPTIM : -s
        CMDLINE1_0 : C:\msys64\usr\bin\g++ -c -DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -I"..\src" -I".\mingw64\include"  -I"C:\msys64\usr\usr\include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a/extern/include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a/simulink/include"  -c -Wall -g -DMCX_EMBED_CL -fno-strict-aliasing -m64 -DMMC_USE_SSE -DHAVE_SSE2 -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4.1 -O3 -fopenmp   -DMCX_CONTAINER -DUSE_OS_TIMER -DUSE_OPENCL -DMMC_XORSHIFT -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -O -DNDEBUG "C:\msys64\home\fangq\space\git\Project\mmc\src\mmclab.cpp" -o C:\msys64\tmp\mex_1481040925092289_7396\mmclab.obj
        CMDLINE1_1 : C:\msys64\usr\bin\g++ -c -DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -I"..\src" -I".\mingw64\include"  -I"C:\msys64\usr\usr\include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a/extern/include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a/simulink/include"  -c -Wall -g -DMCX_EMBED_CL -fno-strict-aliasing -m64 -DMMC_USE_SSE -DHAVE_SSE2 -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4.1 -O3 -fopenmp   -DMCX_CONTAINER -DUSE_OS_TIMER -DUSE_OPENCL -DMMC_XORSHIFT -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -O -DNDEBUG "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\extern\version\cpp_mexapi_version.cpp" -o C:\msys64\tmp\mex_1481040925092289_7396\cpp_mexapi_version.obj
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Building with 'MinGW64 Compiler (C++)'.
Warning: You are using an unsupported version of MinGW Compiler. To install the supported version of MinGW compiler, visit https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-mingw-support-package.html.
 For a list of currently supported compilers see: https://www.mathworks.com/support/compilers.
C:\msys64\usr\bin\g++ -c -DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -I"..\src" -I".\mingw64\include"  -I"C:\msys64\usr\usr\include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a/extern/include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a/simulink/include"  -c -Wall -g -DMCX_EMBED_CL -fno-strict-aliasing -m64 -DMMC_USE_SSE -DHAVE_SSE2 -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4.1 -O3 -fopenmp   -DMCX_CONTAINER -DUSE_OS_TIMER -DUSE_OPENCL -DMMC_XORSHIFT -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -O -DNDEBUG "C:\msys64\home\fangq\space\git\Project\mmc\src\mmclab.cpp" -o C:\msys64\tmp\mex_1481040925092289_7396\mmclab.obj
C:\msys64\usr\bin\g++ -c -DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -I"..\src" -I".\mingw64\include"  -I"C:\msys64\usr\usr\include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a/extern/include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a/simulink/include"  -c -Wall -g -DMCX_EMBED_CL -fno-strict-aliasing -m64 -DMMC_USE_SSE -DHAVE_SSE2 -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4.1 -O3 -fopenmp   -DMCX_CONTAINER -DUSE_OS_TIMER -DUSE_OPENCL -DMMC_XORSHIFT -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -O -DNDEBUG "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\extern\version\cpp_mexapi_version.cpp" -o C:\msys64\tmp\mex_1481040925092289_7396\cpp_mexapi_version.obj
C:\msys64\usr\bin\g++ -m64 -Wl,--no-undefined -static -fopenmp "c:\Windows\System32\OpenCL.dll" -fopenmp -shared -static -s -Wl,"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/exportsmexfileversion.def" C:\msys64\tmp\mex_1481040925092289_7396\mmclab.obj C:\msys64\tmp\mex_1481040925092289_7396\cpp_mexapi_version.obj "built/xorshift128p_rand.o" "built/simpmesh.o" "built/tettracing.o" "built/mcx_utils.o" "built/tictoc.o" "built/mmc.o" "built/cjson/cJSON.o" "built/mmc_host.o" "built/highordermesh.o" "built/mmc_cl_utils.o" "built/mmc_cl_host.o"  -L"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\extern\lib\win64\mingw64" -llibmx -llibmex -llibmat -o C:\msys64\home\fangq\space\git\Project\mmc\mmclab\mmc.mexw64
Recompile embedded version with '-DMATLAB_MEXCMD_RELEASE=R2017b'
C:\msys64\usr\bin\g++ -c -DMATLAB_DEFAULT_RELEASE=R2017b  -DUSE_MEX_CMD   -m64 -DMATLAB_MEX_FILE  -I"..\src" -I".\mingw64\include"  -I"C:\msys64\usr\usr\include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a/extern/include" -I"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a/simulink/include"  -c -Wall -g -DMCX_EMBED_CL -fno-strict-aliasing -m64 -DMMC_USE_SSE -DHAVE_SSE2 -msse -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4.1 -O3 -fopenmp   -DMCX_CONTAINER -DUSE_OS_TIMER -DUSE_OPENCL -DMMC_XORSHIFT -fexceptions -fno-omit-frame-pointer -O -DNDEBUG "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\extern\version\cpp_mexapi_version.cpp" -o C:\msys64\tmp\mex_1481040925092289_7396\cpp_mexapi_version.obj -DMATLAB_MEXCMD_RELEASE=R2017b
C:\msys64\usr\bin\g++ -m64 -Wl,--no-undefined -static -fopenmp "c:\Windows\System32\OpenCL.dll" -fopenmp -shared -static -s -Wl,"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a/extern/lib/win64/mingw64/exportsmexfileversion.def" C:\msys64\tmp\mex_1481040925092289_7396\mmclab.obj C:\msys64\tmp\mex_1481040925092289_7396\cpp_mexapi_version.obj "built/xorshift128p_rand.o" "built/simpmesh.o" "built/tettracing.o" "built/mcx_utils.o" "built/tictoc.o" "built/mmc.o" "built/cjson/cJSON.o" "built/mmc_host.o" "built/highordermesh.o" "built/mmc_cl_utils.o" "built/mmc_cl_host.o"  -L"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\extern\lib\win64\mingw64" -llibmx -llibmex -llibmat -o C:\msys64\home\fangq\space\git\Project\mmc\mmclab\mmc.mexw64
MEX completed successfully.
fangq@zen:~/space/git/Project/mmc/src$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc
fangq@zen:~/space/git/Project/mmc/src$ which g++
/usr/bin/g++
fangq@zen:~/space/git/Project/mmc/src$ which cc
/usr/bin/cc
fangq@zen:~/space/git/Project/mmc/src$ gcc --version
gcc (GCC) 9.3.0
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
```

Comment: Those are functions defined in Posix systems, Windows is not such a system, and therefore doesn’t define it. You can copy the header files, but the system still doesn’t provide the functions. Cygwin has a library that implements most Posix functions, and therefore you can compile your code using Cygwin. MSYS does not have such a library, and therefore you cannot compile with MSYS.

Answer (score 3):

What is the reason you included `ioctl.h`?

Copying that header from somewhere else is a bad idea. At best it will define functions for which libraries don't exist causing linker errors.

Typically you would need to use Windows alternatives for whatever IOCTL stuff you do on other platforms.

I tried to compile MMC on Windows with MSYS2 removing this include and the build succeeded:

```
patch -ulbf src/mcx_utils.c << EOF
@@ -35,3 +35,5 @@
 #include <time.h>
+#ifndef _WIN32
 #include <sys/ioctl.h>
+#endif
 #include "mcx_utils.h"
EOF
sed -i.bak -e "s/^EXTRALIB\s*+*=.*$/& -Wl,--as-needed -lwinmm/" commons/Makefile_common.mk
~/buildstatus.sh build &&
 make -Csrc CC=gcc PLATFORM=MINGW32 &&
 echo Success
```